# RuntimeError: Missing "jwks_uri" in metadata for flask and Google authlib

Tags: python, flask, flask-oauthlib

[Showing the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SCy9y.png)

Not sure why the error is occurring as I have registered the oauth and have even downgraded my authlib version to 0.12.1 and still no fix. The main overarching issue is that I get an internal server error of 500 with the flask app and this jwks_uri showed up as the runtime error.

Comment: Please copy and paste the error here instead of sharing screenshots.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure what your code looks like, but when you register via oauth.register
do you have server_metadata_url? Not having server_metadata_url made my app throw the following error:

- RuntimeError: Missing "jwks_uri" in metadata

"AUTH0_DOMAIN" in this instance would be your auth0 domain.

```
auth0 = oauth.register(
    'auth0',
    client_id=CLIENT_ID,
    client_secret=CLIENT_SECRET,
    api_base_url="https://" + AUTH0_DOMAIN,
    access_token_url="https://" + AUTH0_DOMAIN + "/oauth/token",
    authorize_url="https://" + AUTH0_DOMAIN + "/authorize",
    client_kwargs={
        'scope': 'openid profile email',
    },
server_metadata_url=f'https://{AUTH0_DOMAIN}/.well-known/openid-configuration'
)
```

You can scroll through the official tutorial to the section that has a snippet of code similar to the one I have shown above.

https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/webapp/python/01-login

Answer (score 1):

if you are using  Google authlib just add
server_metadata_url= 'https://accounts.google.com/.well-known/openid-configuration' to the oauth.register
it worked for me,
For example:

```
oauth.register(
    name="google",
    client_id = "your client id",
    client_secret= "your client secret"
    access_token_url= "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token",
    access_token_params=None,
    authorize_url= "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth",
    authorize_params=None,
    api_base_url= "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/",
    client_kwargs= {"scope": "openid email profile"},
    server_metadata_url= 'https://accounts.google.com/.well-known/openid-configuration'
)
```

Comment: This answer is similar in nature to the proceeding answer which appears to provide an answer to the OPs question.

Answer (score 0):

this was what worked for me

```py
google = oauth.register(
    name='google',
    client_id='',
    client_secret='',
    access_token_url='https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token',
    access_token_params=None,
    authorize_url='https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth',
    authorize_params=None,
    api_base_url='https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/',
    userinfo_endpoint='https://openidconnect.googleapis.com/v1/userinfo',
    # This is only needed if using openId to fetch user info
    client_kwargs={'scope': 'openid email profile'},
    jwks_uri = "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/certs"
)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).